# From text file list of list, to Python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which contains around 25K lists .
I added a picture to ilustrate[image]

what I am trying to do is transform this file to a pandas dataframe.
I need it to be that each list is a row in the df, and each cell is one value. wide-columnstore dataset.
I am using this script:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast
import json 

data = open("C:/Users/itamar/Desktop/CouplesMushlam.txt", 'r', encoding = 'windows-1255', errors='ignore').read().replace("\r","").replace("\n","")

remove_doulequotes = data.replace('""', '').replace('"', '')

list_of_str = list(map(lambda x: '"{x}"'.format(x=x), remove_doulequotes.split(",")))

final_data = ", ".join(list_of_str).replace('"[[', '[["').replace(']"','"]').replace(']]"', '"]]').replace('"[', '["').replace(']"]', '"]]')

data_in_list = ast.literal_eval(final_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data_in_list)

df
```

Its not working for some reason and this is what i see:
[image]

any help would be amazing. Im pretty stuck. its worked before i dont know whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It was the spaces.
After I took them off it worked.
U can close the question :)